# Powershell PnP Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, metadata, sharepoint-online

How to upload the files and update the metadata while uploading the file ?
I want to upload a file and (on SharePoint I have a column like deleteFromLocal flag = no, so when i upload the file it should be changed to yes once the file gets uploaded). Is there any way ?

**Code till now:**

```
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 

#Get Connection to the url , #Connect-PnPOnline $URL 

Connect-PnPOnline "Some SharePoint Url" -UseWebLogin

$Files = Get-ChildItem "Local Folder Path which contains the files"

foreach($File in $Files){
    
    $upload = Add-PnPFile -Folder "some folder inside Shared Documents in sharepoint" -Path $File.FullName
    if($upload.UniqueId){
        $successCounter += 1
        $message = "Successfully Uploaded" 
    } else {
        $failCount +=1
        $message = "ERROR - Unable to Upload"
    }
    }
```

Edit: Files are uploading successfully, but I want to modify the column/add a column if possible via this script itself, instead of adding manually(Column - Metadata like a flag which will tell me Yes/no - wether the file is successfully uploaded or not, so that in future when required i can get that flag and do what is necessary).

Comment: since this question is completely about powershell, _how_ is the tag `c#` related?

Comment: Writing the script in c#, Kinda new to scripting and c# :)

Comment: absolutely _nothing_ i your question is related to c#. if you want to _translate_ existing powershell to c# - then say so. and be aware that those kinds of question are _completely_ off-topic. i also ***strongly*** recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - as well as [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sure thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the Yes/No field is "deleteFromLocal", then append -value parameter to set this field like this:

```
$upload = Add-PnPFile -Folder "some folder inside Shared Documents in sharepoint" -Path $File.FullName  -Values @{deleteFromLocal=$true}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, earlier i tried using -values @{deleteFromNas = "Yes"} instead of $true.